# Linear independence

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

In my mind there is a conflict between the "intuitive" definition of **linear** **dependence** of vectors i.e., that :

$\vec{v_1}=k\vec{v_2}$

and the formal definition that says that there must be at least, i.e. 1 is enough, scalar that is non-zero in the linear combination:

$\alpha_1\vec{v_1}+\alpha_2\vec{v_2}+...+\alpha_n\vec{v_n} = \vec{0}$

for me that implies that the case where ALL the OTHER $\alpha_i$ are = 0 must be taken into account*, i.e. that the equation is:

$0\vec{v_1}+0\vec{v_2}+ \alpha_i\vec{v_i}...+0\vec{v_n} = \vec{0} $

and therefore:
$\alpha_i\vec{v_i} = \vec{0}$

=> $\vec{v_i} = \vec{0} $  which is useless ...? That is, for me, the definition should say that there are at least 2 non zero $\alpha_i$... but clearly is it only 1 that is needed.

what is wrong in my reasoning? (I know of course that the definitions are correct)

- of course there are the cases where more than 1 of the scalars is non-zero in which case there is no problem, but my problem is with the at least one.

Comment: I have no idea where your intuitive definition came from, but it's just wrong. That's fundamentally your problem. Further, at least one of the $\alpha_i$ being non-zero does not in any way imply that all of the others are zero, and there's no reason to think that it would: it's not true, even for the simplest case of real numbers (take $\vec{v_1} = 1, \vec{v_2} = -1, \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 1$).

Comment: well the intuitive i mean that $\vec{u}=k\vec{v}$ i guess you agree with that one?

Comment: i mean it implies that there is the situation that all others are non zero, otherwise one should say at least TWO. dont you think? for the logical point of view. At least one means that it can be one non zero .. or more but the case where only 1 is non zero must be taken into account...

Comment: No, I don't, because it's wrong, as demonstrated. And no, it shouldn't say at least 2, because the only difference between the two is the case in which one vector is the zero vector, and in that case "at least 2" gives the wrong answer.

Comment: ok i think i undertand now. I was missing the case when there is only one vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, unless one of the $v_i$'s is the null vector, it *never* happens that only one of the $\alpha_i$'s is $0$. In other words, if $v_1v_2,\ldots,v_n\neq0$ and if $v_1v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly dependent, then there coeffiecients $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ of which at least *two* are non-zero such that$$\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n=0.$$

On the other hand, asserting that **if** at least one of the $\alpha_i$'s is non-zero **then** all others are zero is a *non sequitur*.

Comment: thanks, i think that answers my question. But still i don't understand why you say that at least one is non zero doesn't imply that the others are? For me at least on includes the case that all but one are zero. Of course it also includes cases where 2, are non zero, ... etc

Comment: for me that means that the definition we read everywhere is at least ambiguous... why don't they say "at least two" instead on at least one?! e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence

Comment: You are right *in general*. But the specific case of the situation in which you have non-zero vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$, if there are scalars $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ such that $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n=0$ and if *at least* one of the scalars is non-zero, then there is necessarily another non-zero scalar. It's as if I tell you that I have $4$ integers whose sum is even and such that *at least* one of them is odd. Then there is no way that *only one* of them is odd, since, if this was the case, then the sum of all $4$ of them would be odd, not even.

Comment: You can say *at least two* because that fails, for instance, in the case in which there is a single vector, which happens to be the null vector.

Comment: oh ok. so you mean that the case where only 1 $alpha_i$ is = 0 then necessarily it is the case where there is only 1 vector and it is the 0 vector?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: one more thing.: i guess that this explains that if the zero vector is part of a set of vectors, then this set cannot be independent because you can always have a nonzero scalar that multiplies the zero vector such and the other =0 such that the whole linear combination = the zero vector, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: great , thanks    !